# how to get android app name who is using my rest api in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am develop rest api in asp.net c#. We have many Android app that are using same api. So I want to Store Android App name  which is using my Rest APi in C# ASP.NET

Comment: You can you use a parameter  or follow different authentication process ,log the requests

Comment: Dear Sir, I need to store Android appname when  That android app hit my rest api . So how to get that android appname

Comment: Send Android app name  as parameter

Comment: I need to work without parameter. because app is live. i am using these code but they are working only for web url. not for APPs   Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Android app unique name is basiclly its package name eg:*`com.example.application`* .

**Add a request header to accept this value**. Ask users to include a request header '*PackageID*' which is their app's package id.

```
IEnumerable<string> headerValues = request.Headers.GetValues("PackageID");

var id = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
```

Log this value to DB.

**What more can you do with this ID?**

Yes you can restrict usage of API for a specific Package ID (A specific App).